# Is there a way to forcefully find a CSS selector element/bring it into view?

Tags: css

Let's say for example I'm going through my stylesheet but I can't remember what element a certain CSS selector affects.

Is there any method, tool, or anything that I could do/use to find out what exactly it is affecting?

Thanks!

Comment: You can just use the browser console and execute a jquery script with that selector and find out which all elements are affected by the selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just opened up a random bootstrap template site and did what you where asking for.

[image: Here is the screen shot of it in detail]

Open up your chrome browser (I prefer this as I feel this is easy to debug both Jquery and css) and Press F12, you will get a developer window as in the image.

1. Switch to the console tab.
2. Use Jquery selector to select all
   the intended elements (you can use the same css selector here too
   but just place them inside $('')) Eg: `$('.tab-content') I am trying to find out all the elements with the class tab-content`
3. The result is all the elements
   of that selector.

**NOTE:** This appraoch woud require you to have Jquery loaded into your page. Else the script will throw an error saying $ is not defind.

Comment: With your method, is there a way to actually bring the affected element into view if it's not visible at first?

Comment: If the element is present in the DOM when you run the script then surely it will be displayed in the result.

Comment: What if the element ISN'T present initially, but requires *hovering* or *clicking into* (such as a dropdown item) to bring into view?

Comment: those will be given in the result. When I mean all the elements in the DOM its all the elements which are loaded (even hidden once). But not the ones that will be loaded into DOM in future by jquery or something

Comment: Well, this was very educational. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The inspection of elements feature of the browser is meant for the purpose you want. 
1.Open up the index file in any browser(preferably Mozilla Developer edition), 
2.Right click and Inspect element,
3.Then open the compiled stylesheet. Find out the style element you want to check the effect of.
4. Go back to inspection, remove/add CSS properties and see the effect in real time.

The other way is to use Adobe brackets. It's live preview feature will highlight the section that involves the code snippet, you point your cursor to.

Comment: From the question, what I got is you want to check out the what CSS property affects which element. You could surely use what I suggested to check it out. Besides, I have edited the answer adding and additional method.

Comment: Also, I like Micheal Aaron Safyan's idea of adding a border or background color to it, so as to check out the effected elements.

Comment: What you're suggesting is to use the inspect element feature to see what selectors are affecting a targetted element. What I want is to be able to find out the targeted element **based on the selector alone**.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using your browser's development tools, there are two easy ways to do it that should work in almost any browser (no matter how bad the developer environment).

**Visually**

Temporarily set a border or background color for the selector, like:

```
border: 1px solid red;
```

Or:

```
background: red;
```

This makes it very easy to find the affected elements.

**Programmatically**

On the JavaScript console, use:

```
 // Replace with something that prints the relevant details
 var stringify = function(element) { return element.innerHTML; };

 // Iterate over all affected elements and print relevant info
 var affectedElements = document.querySelectorAll('.your .selector');
 var len = affectedElements.length;
 console.log('Elements affected: ' + len);
 for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var affectedElement = affectedElements[i];
    console.log(
        'Element ' + (i+1) + ':\n' +
         stringify(affectedElement) + '\n\n');
 }
```

Comment: I like that this works, but it just gives me a whole bunch of text that is near un-readable.

Comment: @antonlab, yeah, you need to redefine "stringify" according to what aspects of the affected elements you care about.